# SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values error in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project and am getting the error which is shown in this screenshot:

[image]

This is my homework so any help would be appreciated.

I tried to change controller and repository but nothing changed. Code is below - `ClubController`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using webHomework.Data;
using webHomework.Interfaces;
using webHomework.Models;
using webHomework.ViewModels;

namespace webHomework.Controllers
{
    public class ClubController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IClubRepository _clubRepository;
        private readonly IPhotoService _photoService;

        public ClubController(IClubRepository clubRepository, IPhotoService photoService)
        {
            _clubRepository = clubRepository;
            _photoService = photoService;
        }      

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<Club> clubs = await _clubRepository.GetAll();
            return View(clubs);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(int id)
        {
            Club club = await _clubRepository.GetByIdAsync(id);
            return View(club);
        }

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateClubViewModel clubVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _photoService.AddPhotoAsync(clubVM.Image);

                var club = new Club
                {
                    Title = clubVM.Title,
                    Description = clubVM.Description,
                    Image = result.Url.ToString(),
                    Address = new Address
                    {
                        Street = clubVM.Address.Street,
                        City = clubVM.Address.City,
                        State = clubVM.Address.State,
                    }
                };

                _clubRepository.Add(club);

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Photo upload failed");
            }

            return View(clubVM);
        }
    }
}
```

`ClubRepository`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using webHomework.Data;
using webHomework.Interfaces;
using webHomework.Models;

namespace webHomework.Repository
{
    public class ClubRepository : IClubRepository
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public ClubRepository (ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public bool Add(Club club)
        {
            _context.Add(club);
            return Save();
        }

        public bool Delete(Club club)
        {
            _context.Remove(club);
            return Save();
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Club>> GetAll()
        {
            return await _context.Clubs.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<Club> GetByIdAsync(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Clubs.Include(i => i.Address).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Club>> GetClubByCity(string city)
        {
            return await _context.Clubs.Where(c => c.Address.City.Contains(city)).ToListAsync();
        }

        public bool Save()
        {
            var saved = _context.SaveChanges();
            return saved > 0 ? true : false;
        }

        public bool Update(Club club)
        {
            _context.Update(club);
            return Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @mason i kinda got your point but as i am newbie on .net development i don't know which setup i have done with details. Any chance to contact u via discord or telegram ?

Comment: I guess your class `Club` has an `int` property which is mapped to a `nullable number` field on database. If this is true there is a `null` value on your database which cannot be mapped to a `non-nullable int` property in C#.

Comment: @SebastianS. yes Sebastian I have Club and it has int property and rn for 1 of them it says null on the database so that i got error right ? how can i fix this? Any chance to contact u via discord or telegram ?

Comment: You can declarate your `int` property as nullable: `int?`.

Comment: @SebastianS. yes i did at the time u said and it worked thank u :)

Comment: @Lambersonistaken this site is not for personal help as such, and therefore you shouldn't be asking members to contact you directly. From the front-page "A community-based space to find and contribute answers to technical challenges" i.e. its intended that questions asked here will continue to help people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `int` property which is mapped to database number field as nullable with `int?`.